# How to read files

Tags: c#, c#-3.0, c#-to-vb.net

How to read files in `C#`?

What are the avaibable methods?

Comment: I had been trying text files first.

Comment: I am not sure if this kind of question is appropriate for SO. There are countless resources on the net about this..

Comment: See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181634/simplest-efficient-ways-to-read-binary-and-ascii-files-to-string-or-similar-in-v/181766#181766)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, there's the [File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx) class.

Comment: txtSourceFileName is a textbox - this isn't working...please help

string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(txtSourceFileName)

Comment: @user667389: Close.  You're probably getting an error about the type being passed to the `ReadAllText` method being incorrect.  You want to reference the `.Text` property of the `TextBox` in order to get its contents.  Try `string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(txtSourceFileName.Text);`

Comment: It gives me an error: 
txtSourceFileName.Text is Null -
i want this value to be input by user what to do?

Comment: @user667389: Is there a value being input?  Is it a valid path to a text file?  You'll definitely want to do input validation, which is an entirely separate topic from this one.  At the very least, wrap the call in a conditional to check `string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSourceFileName.Text)` but even more than that you'll want to use other methods (on the `File` class) to see if the file exists, etc.  Be careful not to allow system-compromising input.

Answer (score 4):

Vague question, but on the information given and assuming text files:

```
string fileData = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\path\to\your\file.txt");
```

However if you are reading binary files, xml files etc there are other ways.

Comment: You're looking for the documentation. http://www.google.com/search?q=.net+how+to+read+text+files, first three results.

Comment: @user667389: He did.  He provided a line of code which reads the entire text file into a string.  It was very kind of him, actually.  If there's more you need, you may want to be more specific.

Answer (score 4):

[How to: Read From a Text File (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezwyzy7b.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for every single class in `System.IO` except for `MemoryStream`.
For more details, see [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I always read .txt files with System.IO.StreamReader

```
StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@"C:\Windows\System32\etc.txt");
```

And then you can read from the file with

```
string blah = file.ReadLine();
```

or

```
string blahblah = file.Read()
```

Comment: What if i am getting the Path from a textbox?

Comment: Then use TextBox.Text instead of the hardcoded path in the example

Comment: so it would be like new StreamReader(TextBox1.Text);

Answer (score 1):

```
include System.IO; //The input/output class in C# .NET

//Main Class etc.
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(string Path);
string output = sr.Read(); //output data
```

C# tends to be very picky with reading data so I suggest reading binary data rather than using StreamReader.

Answer (score 0):

Using `System.IO.StreamReader` and the `.ReadLine()` method will work if you need a text file line by line.